# How get a distinct list of document fields using NEST?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have just started with Elasticsearch and am using the NEST API for my .Net application.  I have an index and some records inserted.  I am now trying to get a distinct list of document field values.  I have this working in Postman.  **I do not know how to port the JSON aggregation body to a NEST call**.  Here is the call I am trying to port to the NEST C# API:

```
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
    "hosts": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "host"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result which is my next question.  **How would I parse or assign a POCO to the result?**  I am only interested in the distinct list of the field value in this case 'host'.  I really just want an enumerable of strings back.  I do not care about the count at this point.

```
{
"took": 0,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": {
        "value": 3,
        "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
},
"aggregations": {
    "hosts": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "hoyt",
                "doc_count": 3
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the results I am after with the following code:

```
        var result = await client.SearchAsync<SyslogEntryIndex>(s => s.Size(0).Aggregations(a => a.Terms("hosts", t => t.Field(f => f.Host))));

        List<string> hosts = new List<string>();
        foreach (BucketAggregate v in result.Aggregations.Values)
        {
           foreach (KeyedBucket<object> item in v.Items)
            {
                hosts.Add((string)item.Key);
            }
        }
        return hosts;
```

Comment: Can use the `result.Aggregations.Terms(“hosts”)` to get the terms aggregation. See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/terms-aggregation-usage.html#_handling_responses_61